# Dependent dropdown for department and course

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii

I a working on a dependent dropdown in yii, I want the department dropdown to autoload with the departments depending on what faculty I select, the course dropdown to load with courses once i select a department, the code almost works except that the dropdowns are updating themselves rather than the dropdowns beneath. How can I make them update properly?

this is the 
views/site/newuser:

```
      `<div class="row">` 
       <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'faculty_id'); ?>
       <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'faculty_id',
        CHtml::listData(Faculty::model()->findAll(),'id','faculty_name'),

    array(
    'prompt'=>'Select Faculty',
    'ajax' => array(
    'type'=>'POST',
    'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('site/loaddepartment'),
    'update'=>'#NewUser_faculty_id',
    'data'=>array('faculty_id'=>'js:this.value'),)));
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'faculty_id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'department_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'department_id',
         CHtml::listData(Department::model()->findAll(),'id','department_name'),
        array(
    'prompt'=>'Select Department',
    'ajax' => array(
    'type'=>'POST',
    'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('site/loadcourses'),
    'update'=>'#NewUser_department_id',
    'data'=>array('department_id'=>'js:this.value'),)));



    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'department_id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'course_id'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('department_name','', array(), array(
    'prompt'=>'Select Course'

    )); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'course_id'); ?>
</div>


<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

this is in the controller:

```
public function actionloaddepartment()
{
$data=Department::model()->findAll('faculty_id=:faculty_id', 
array(':faculty_id'=>(int) $_POST['faculty_id']));

$data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','department_name');

echo "<option value=''>Select Department</option>";
foreach($data as $value=>$department_name)
echo CHtml::tag('option',    array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($department_name),true);
  }


public function actionloadcourses()

  {

 $data=Courses::model()->findAll('department_id=:department_id', 
 array(':department_id'=>(int) $_POST['department_id']));

 $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','course_name');

echo "<option value=''>Select course</option>";
foreach($data as $value=>$course_name)
echo CHtml::tag('option',    array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($course_name),true);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

so, I was able to get a fix, Thank God, here it is, so incase any one might need it

this is the new/views/site/newuser:

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'first_name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'first_name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'first_name'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'last_name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'last_name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'last_name'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'faculty_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'faculty_id',
        CHtml::listData(Faculty::model()->findAll(),'id','faculty_name'),

    array(
    'prompt'=>'Select Faculty',
    'ajax' => array(
    'type'=>'POST',
    'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('site/loaddepartment'),
    'update'=>'#department_id',

    'data'=>array('faculty_id'=>'js:this.value'
    ),
    )));
   ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'faculty_id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'department_id'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('department_id','', array(),

        array(

    'ajax' => array(
    'type'=>'POST',
    'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('site/loadcourses'),
    'update'=>'#course_id',

    'data'=>array('department_id'=>'js:this.value'
    ),
    )))


     ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'department_id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'course_id'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('course_id','', array()

    )?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'course_id'); ?>
</div>


<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
</div>
```

This is the New controller:

```
  public function actionloaddepartment()
 {
 $data=Department::model()->findAll('faculty_id=:faculty_id', 
 array(':faculty_id'=>(int) $_POST['faculty_id']));

 $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','department_name');


  foreach($data as $value=>$department_name)

  echo CHtml::tag('option',   array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($department_name),true);
  }


      public function actionloadcourses()
      {
      $data=Courses::model()->findAll('department_id=:department_id', 
       array(':department_id'=>(int) $_POST['department_id']));

      $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','course_name');


   foreach($data as $value=>$course_name)
   echo CHtml::tag('option',    array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($course_name),true);
    }
```